# How to send a message from a Wi-fi board to cellphone

Tags: wifi, fpga

I am currently working on something that requires sending a message from FPGA board to a cellphone.
I try to understand if it possible to connect to the FPGA board, a Wi-fi board that can deliver an sms.
I have seen some suggestions in google, but prefer to advise here he best way to perform such thing.

Comment: You need to clarify the question, which FPGA and which wifi chip. Theoretically, there should be no problems implementing an exchange protocol with a Wi-Fi IC and a FPGA.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.